# CIFS mounting in /etc/fstab stopped working in Ubuntu 16.04 (mount ignores entries)

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I recently upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu MATE 16.04. In my /etc/fstab file, there are entries like this:

```
//192.168.1.1/mk /home/michael/smbshares/mk cifs noauto,iocharset=utf8,uid=michael,gid=users,credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 0 0
```

This used to work before. Now, at boot time, nothing happens and when I later do a "mount -av", it prints a line like that:

```
/home/michael/smbshares/mk: ignored
```

However, manually mounting using

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/mk /home/michael/smbshares/mk -o noauto,iocharset=utf8,uid=michael,gid=users,credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775
```

works.

How can I get that functionality back? Or is there a different way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Hi Michael. Try mounting the share with the `noperm` option added to the entry in your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: AFAIK `noauto` means it can only be mounted explicitly (i.e. not at boot-time, and not with the `-a` option) - see `man mount`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by sempaiscuba and stelldriver, I replaced noauto by noperm and now it works like it did before.